# I want to display toast message after click on enter key on virtual keyboard

Tags: android, android-virtual-keyboard

**please find the updated code below.**

Following is the code:

```
package com.Wase.edittext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.Wase.edittext.R;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

 private EditText edittext;
 private EditText edittext1;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_android_app);

    addKeyListener();
 edittext.requestFocus();
}



 public void addKeyListener() {

    // get edittext component
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);



    // add a keylistener to keep track user input
    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
    {
        edittext1.requestFocus();
    }

    edittext1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onEditorAction(TextView a, int b, KeyEvent c) {

    // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
    if ((c.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        && (c.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

        //hide the keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext1.getWindowToken(), 0);
    // display a floating message
        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            edittext.getText() + " " + edittext1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

        return false;
}
 });
        return false;
}
    });
 }
}
```

This code is only for keyboard click or system keyboard click. I want to hide the virtual key board and display the toast message on click on enter key of android virtual key board.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a new `onKeyListener` to edittext1 everytime a key is pressed in edittext... is that actually what you want to do?

The code you've got to detect when the enter key is pressed seems fine. You will need to add the following code to close the keyboard and do a toast.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, "My message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: I agree with the comment, but the main problem here the toast is only displaying on click on Physical keyboard not via andriod virtual key board.

Comment: Try using `editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()` etc. Instead of your `onKeyListener`

Comment: I wrote the code like this after modification.it is given issue on OnEditorActionListener() and public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)..  how to resolve3 this.. code is as follows

Comment: onKey isn't a method in the OnEditorActionListener() I will change my answer to show a bit more code

Comment: editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
        {
            edittext1.requestFocus();
        }

Comment: I have updated my answer so hopefully you can now see what I mean

Comment: edittext1.setOnEditorActionListener(newTextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Overridepublic boolean onEditorAction(TextView a, int b, KeyEvent c) {
 if ((c.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
&& (c.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext1.getWindowToken(), 0);
Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,edittext.getText() + " " + edittext1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: This above code not dispalying any toast just hiding the virtual keyboard

Comment: Just having a look now

Comment: post link to it here when you've done it. Or just edit this question - up to you

Comment: able to notice the issue??/

Comment: This looks like it should work, not sure whats happening. Did you say it is closing the keyboard ok, just not toasting?

Comment: The main issue was keyboard should close and should toast. but now. It is not toasting by hiding the keyboard.

Comment: previosuly it was toasting. now not taosting at all after hiding the keyboard

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss with this one. You could try moving the toast to before the keyboard closing code and see if that helps?

Comment: If you are avialable on watsapp i can send you the apk file. can you have a look into it

Comment: I am about to go out for the rest of the day, so if you need it looking at quickly I suggest creating a new question. If not I can continue looking tomorrow.

Comment: rasied a new question.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747005/i-want-to-display-toast-message-after-click-on-enter-key-on-virtual-keyboard

Comment: edittext1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
          public boolean onEditorAction(TextView a, int b, KeyEvent c) {
 
  // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
   if (b == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || b == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||   
       c.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && c.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)